# PHP SOAP read the binary response from Cisco NBR downloadNBRStorageFile API and create .ARF file out of it

Tags: php, laravel, api, soap, webex

I am trying to use the NBR API for downloading the recording from WebEx server. When I run a downloadNBRStorageFile SOAP request(using postman) it responds with the webex recording in a stream.

**In response**

When I check the response from the API in postman it looks like this:

```
------=_Part_633_1893304738.1500351436145
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: 
<FFFA7DB08063F23702D0ECA3D281DCD3>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns1:downloadNBRStorageFileResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="NBRStorageService">
                <ns1:downloadNBRStorageFileReturn xsi:type="soapenc:Array" soapenc:arrayType="ns1:DataHandler[2]" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
                    <item href="cid:146662A992D4B0C9BDC471A0E338E684"/>
                    <item href="cid:0EFC5015D567DB498B49530FE4FABDD7"/>
                </ns1:downloadNBRStorageFileReturn>
            </ns1:downloadNBRStorageFileResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_633_1893304738.1500351436145
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id:
    <146662A992D4B0C9BDC471A0E338E684>

Demo-20170424 0824-1.arf
5402
false
------=_Part_633_1893304738.1500351436145
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Id: 
        <0EFC5015D567DB498B49530FE4FABDD7>

X�\Y=XH���H��H�   XBW$HS��X#s3�=S��XXBW*x0Demo.3040047907   958102358�3s#O"f�P    IIMB Host
randomstrings�
            <random_strings>
                <random_string1>rIhldZZp3nPCGAwmt+L3kLKjBsgIygtgyuaBN26TN3E=</random_string1>
                <random_string2>lKxADufR/Rn3XX9djkuZqGIHmiQxaPqP2J39+bze1vY=</random_string2>
            </random_strings>lx2s    nbr_token1047388207:1493022291nbr_record_durationX��Snbr_starttime_ms�7�Sxesession_typec_session_idfc_pdvideo_idg[xe  ..  X  [xe`..�855 ?xhsession_typec_session_idi�xh`�
            <chat ver="1.0">
                <mtype>5</mtype>
                <NodeID>0</NodeID>
                <UserName>
                    <![CDATA[IIMB Host]]>
                </UserName>
                <RoleSet>3</RoleSet>
                <Visible>1</Visible>
                <UserType>0</UserType>
                <UIT>0</UIT>
                <GuestID>0</GuestID>
            </chat>gxjWBX_SESSION_USER_DATA_EUREKAsession_typec_session_idk7xj`
U33558529?xlsession_typec_session_idm/xl00Mjxl`=
            <user FG="6" KD="0" NM="IIMB Host" EM="****@**********.**" />�xnsession_typePRIVILEGE_TICKETJNEW_ENC_FORMAT_002RzH//wAAAATvfbFUoMwtWmGIzR9U5Yk2tUsgVMNFlzpXprogwKW1qw==FLASH_RSC_IDIMAGE_RSC_ID-xn`gxoWBX_SESSION_USER_DATA_EUREKAsession_typec_session_idpoxqWBX_SESSION_USER_DATA_EUREKAsession_typec_session_idrxx` IIMB Host   000.0.0.0���f�P�
            <CMgr ver="1.0">
                <UAID>37</UAID>
                <CS>6</CS>
                <FG>8288</FG>
                <PG>95055</PG>
                <EA>****@**********.**</EA>
                <UIT>0</UIT>
                <NBRCapability>1</NBRCapability>
                <CMRClientVersion>0</CMRClientVersion>
                <JMT>1493022269</JMT>
            </CMgr>x
xx!958102358,�NBR2EVERRUN4�NBR2_RECORD_VERSION2.33NBR2_Platform_FlagXp
NBR2Status2XQ

NBR2Status2Xz

NBR2Status2�R2s�XBW$HT��X#s3�HS��XXBW*XBW$HT��X#s3��S��XXBW*�H(F��
QuickStart������������������(��������������WPDFS46
�{������������������������
QuickStarteH(oW� Information�����������������((��������������H(p������������/��/�=��������U�/�=
������������������fH(pX�page 1�������������//���������ZH(pL���������������������)���������?XBW$HT��X#s3�HS��XXBW*XBW$HT��X#s3��S��XXBW*gHY
YO9{VO"�3s#,VmF7XvR8d049Hlf4302g1x7MUZEyah3G9Zw1l87U4UI=*5C$�Oj��P�h�gH�
YO9{VO"�3s#,VmF7XvR8d049Hlf4302g1x7MUZEyah3G9Zw1l87U4UI=*5C$�Oj��P�h�H
H�
H�(
H;4
H�?
H�K
XBW$HT��X#s3�HS��XXBW*XBW$HT��X#s3�S��XXBW*gH�
YDO9{VO"�3s#,VmF7XvR8d049Hlf4302g1x7MUZEyah3G9Zw1l87U4UI=*5C$�Oj��P�h�gH�
YDO9{VO"�3s#,VmF7XvR8d049Hlf4302g1x7MUZEyah3G9Zw1l87U4UI=*5C$�Oj��P�h�
------=_Part_633_1893304738.1500351436145--
```

**Response header** is

```
Content-Type → multipart/related;
type="text/xml"; 
start="<6CD29D3FD60E4438F6DC0087CF25E12D>";
boundary="----=_Part_627_84395761.1500349931712"
Date →Tue, 18 Jul 2017 03:52:11 GMT
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

How to create the .arf file from above response and also get the file name(Demo-20170424 0824-1.arf) in the above response using PHP?

Comment: I am able to parse the response using github.com/Riverline/multipart-parser package.

Comment: Would you be able to supply an example of how you did this? We could then mark this question answered.

Answer (score 1):

Install the PHP package from https://packagist.org/packages/sathish/webex using composer or else clone it from https://github.com/rsathishtechit/webex. This package can be used to connect to and download the recording from WebEx NBR API.

To parse the Multipart data from WebEx use http://github.com/Riverline/multipart-parser package.

For more details refer the README.md section of https://packagist.org/packages/sathish/webex.